# On Windows 7 using imagemagick to convert from HTML to PNG

Tags: html, png, imagemagick

By any chance on Windows 7 using a batch file via DOS and/or Powershell is it possible to use imagemagick to convert from HTML to png? (not trying to capture webpages)

I have several directories of HTML pages that I would like to convert to PNG.  I have Imagemagick installed and if possible would like to use it or another opensource/freeware solution to convert the html pages to PNG.

Thanks for any insights.

Comment: Just to clarify: do you want to show the source code as an image, or do you want to show a pre-rendered page?

Comment: @Barbarrosa I would not like to convert the HTML source code, but like to convert the HTML rendered page (what you see in the browser) into an image.

Comment: HTML isn't an image format so it can't be converted with Imagemagick. You actually are trying to capture a webpage.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Phantom JS needs a little bit of scripting (js) but it is very convenient to get the rendered html converted into an image : http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/wiki/QuickStart#Rendering

Comment: PhantomJS is an easiest way to deal with webkit, and webkit is the best tool for automated rendering of HTML to images.
Good answer, @bobylito!

Comment: Thanks for this recommendation.  I finally got an opportunity to be able to try this out.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Yes ! You can make PNG images from HTML render pages with *imageMagick*.
Type in a terminal window (*cmd.exe* in MS Windows 7) :

```
convert yourPage.html Newimage.png
```

It is the same command line in Linux.